# Properly Force Mathematica to Simplify Log Expressions/Rules

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to be able to expand $\log(x^n e^x) = n \log(x) +x$:

```
FullSimplify[Log[x^n Exp[x]], x > 0 && Element[n, Integers] && n > 1]
```

yields

```
Log[E^x x^n]
```

whereas

```
-1 +FullSimplify[Log[x^n Exp[x]] + 1,  x > 0 && Element[n, Integers] && n > 1]
```

yields

```
x + n Log[x]
```

what gives? Maybe it recognizes that I want to do arithmetic outside the log, so it then simplifies the expression; if that's the case, how can I force it to do that without hacking it by adding and subtracting 1?

thanks!

Comment: Can use PowerExpand with assumptions. The use of assumptions, while not really needed in your example, is good practice for cases where branch cuts might otherwise inadvertently be crossed. `PowerExpand[Log[x^n Exp[x]], 
 Assumptions -> x > 0 && Element[n, Integers] && n > 1]

Out[1]= x + n Log[x]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe:

```
FullSimplify[PowerExpand@Log[x^n Exp[x]], 
 x > 0 && Element[n, Integers] && n > 1]
```

> ```
> x + n Log[x]
> ```